# How can I convert my string public key to RSAParameters?

Tags: c#, string, encryption, key, rsa

Ive got a public key which can be used to decrypt a message. On my csharp server I am recieving a message which has been encrypted with a private key. The server knows the public key and wants to encrypt it. The issue is that RSACryptoServiceProvider doesnt accept string as a key, but only RSAParameters format. How can I turn my public key (which is currently a string) into a RSAParameters type?

If there is a different way to decrypt without converting my key to RSAParameters, let me know.

This is the public key:

```
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS1NSUdmTUEwR0NTcUdTSWIzRFFFQkFRVUFBNEdOQURDQmlRS0JnUUM4TlpkLzhUYUxSMStyT0JYRjdGYzZ2RFA0blRUdTlQNmVjcDd2YzRhTk1pVUorRXM2b2YrRFNvY25wL0drazJVa0k5OHlmVTZwMHNTa3NEcWV1R0hwc1AwaS9oYnlRYlM5RVBreW5HT1VicVpnRSt1SVN0SHVyd2ozaFJKQ1ZkbktKWkxVRVYvSDZCM3Z0SGZITG5GemIrd0E4VkhPeWlEWjVZenp3RHRoR1FJREFRQUItLS0tLUVORCBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0=
```

Comment: Encrypt with the private key and decrypt with the public key??? It should be the other way around. Or are you talking about signing/verifying?

Comment: Its for verifying, and the key is currently in string format, not byte array

Comment: _public key which is currently a string_ isn't a proper description. Keys can be in different formats and also as strings. You need to describe this in more detail or alternatively, post a test key. Also post your C# code and .NET version.

Comment: I added the key to the question

Comment: If you Base64 decode the posted public key you get a PEM encoded X.509/SPKI key. The import of this format depends on your .NET version. As of .NET Core 3.0 DER encoded keys of this format can be imported directly. Below that or in .NET Framework, BouncyCastle is the easiest way.

Answer (score -1):

Your key is Base64 encoded. I can guess that because it uses A-Z, a-z and 0-9 only and ends with `=`. You get the bytes back by decoding:

```
byte[] someBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(someBase64);
```

If you convert these bytes back into an ASCII string using

```
var publicKeyInGuard = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(someBytes);
```

you'll find that it gives you

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8NZd/8
TaLR1+rOBXF7Fc6vDP4nTTu9P6ecp7vc4aNMiUJ+Es6of
+DSocnp/Gkk2UkI98yfU6p0sSksDqeuGHpsP0i/hbyQbS
9EPkynGOUbqZgE+uIStHurwj3hRJCVdnKJZLUEV/H6B3v
tHfHLnFzb+wA8VHOyiDZ5YzzwDthGQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

In .NET Core 3 and later, you can then strip the guard and process the contents as Base64 again and import them as RSA parameters:

```cs
var publicKeyBase64 = publicKeyInGuard
            .Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyBase64);

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKeyBytes, out _);
    var rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    // use the RSAParameters here
}
```

Comment: If you examine his bytes you'll see they're not in the correct format to use this.